# Counting all points in polygon where the name of polygon and point matches with SQL

Tags: qgis, sql, overlapping-features, point-in-polygon, count

In QGIS I have two datasets: (1) one with points that have two fields, the unique identifier `"PK"` and `"species"` - either H, L or G (2) second with polygons of areas, again with unique `"PK"` and each polygon has `"species"` either H, L or G.

I'm not very experienced with SQLite and struggling to find the query that would return the total number of points which lie within a polygon with a matching species.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this query :

```sql
SELECT
  area.pk,
  COUNT(*) AS nb_matching_species_within_the_area
FROM
  my_point_layer pt,
  my_area_layer area
WHERE
  ST_CONTAINS(area.geometry, pt.geometry)  -- inverse of ST_CONTAINS is ST_WITHIN
  AND pt.species = area.species
GROUP BY area.pk
;
```

Make a selection `FROM` your two datasets, make 2 conditions : area `ST_CONTAINS` points `AND` points `pt.species` equals `area.species`.

Then, `GROUP BY` area `P`rimary `K`ey and `COUNT` all records to have the number of matching records, so points within the area with the same species.